# Play video (from streaming) in iPhone with Ionic 3/Cordova iOS app from Node Js, without so much time loading

Tags: ios, node.js, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework

First, sorry because this is not an special code issue (I can play videos in iPhone), so I'm not attaching any of my code, but asking for technical solution.

I'm developing a mobile applicaton (and also a webapp) that plays videos which come from a Nde js server. At first I noticed that in Safari, you can only play videos from streaming (which is also the best practice in the rest of the browsers), but it was very slow (so much time loading the video).

I came accross this piece of code, and the post of the author, it helped me to improve my server side streaming code:

https://github.com/davidgatti/How-to-Stream-Movies-using-NodeJS/blob/master/routes/video.js

I didn't need to change anything in the webapp, but now I can  play videos much faster in Mac/Safari (in HTML5 I have simple  tags). 
But nothing changed in the Ionic app... And I don't know how to follow or where the problem could be (ionic/cordova or Node JS).

What can be the point I can be missing? Any link, known bug in ionic, or trick would help a lot.

**UPDATE:**
I'm trying with .mov and .mp4 video files. What's the ideal format (or compression) for iPhone?

**UPDATE 2:**
It's a good choice to handle videos with a cloud video solution like uStream, and embed it like an iframe (as provided solution from ustream)? Nothing more seem to work on improving time of load, managing videos on my own server and ionic client.

Thanks so much

Comment: What about the videos format? Not every type of video is streameable, in fact you must use selected formats with specific compression modes to enable on demand streaming, otherwise the entire file will be downloaded first, causing endless delays.